# rexEX extract only important text

Tags: python, regex

I'm new at regex and I have to extract some data that are in-between: `[[(.*?)]]`, however not those that have `<small>` after.

```
movie = \'\'[[**Iron Man (film)|Iron Man**]]\'\'<br>\'\'[[The Incredible Hulk]]\'\' 
<small>([[List of Post-credits Scenes|pre-credits scene]])</small><br>\'\'[[**Iron Man 
2**]]\'\'<br>\'\'[[Thor (film)|Thor]]\'\' <small>(mentioned)</small><br>\'\'[[**The 
Avenger**s]]\'\'<br>\'\'[[**Iron Man 3**]]\'\'<br>\'\
```

I only want the text marked as **fat**. Right now im using this pattern: `movie_pattern = r'\'\'\[\[(.*?)\]\]\'\'<br>'`. But I that doesn't work as that returns:

```
['Iron Man (film)|Iron Man',
 "The Incredible Hulk]]'' <small>([[List of Post-credits Scenes|pre-credits scene]])</small><br>''[[Iron Man 2",
 "Thor (film)|Thor]]'' <small>(mentioned)</small><br>''[[The Avengers",
 'Iron Man 3',
```

Do you have any idea in how to this?  (its in python)

Comment: Maybe `\[\[(.*?)]](?!\W*</?small>)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example data, the part after the `]]` that should not follow is either `''` or `)` followed by optional whitespace chars followed by either `<small>` or `</small>`

If there can be newlines in the match, you could use a tempered greedy token approach, and have a dot match a newline:

```
(?s)\[\[((?:(?!]]).)*)]](?!(?:''|\))\s*</?small>)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?s)` Inline modifier to have the dot match a newline
- `\[\[` Match `[[`
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `(?:(?!]]).)*` Match any char including newlines if what is directly to the right is not `]]`
- `)` Close capture **group 1**
- `]]` Match literally
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert that to the right is not

  - `(?:''|\))` Match either `''` or `)`
  - `\s*</?small>` Match optional whitespace chars and either `<small>` or `</small>`
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lbjsI1/1)

Comment: Thanks! It still seems to catch the ones with <small> which I don't understand why.. :(

Comment: @NoraSeinfield The matches of the capture groups in the regex demo are correct right?

Comment: @NoraSeinfield Can you add an example to this demo, and then save the regex101 link and share the link the comments here? https://regex101.com/r/lbjsI1/1

Comment: It works now, my bad! Thank you! It was because the movies were mentioned other places in the text as well, but I found a work around by splitting the text so only that part was considered :-)